# how to get the jstree work 

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

this is my file omploader.org/vNWJieg/1.png:

and this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>jsTree v.1.0 - full featured demo</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="_lib/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="_lib/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="_lib/jquery.hotkeys.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jstree.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_docs/!style.css" />
 <style type="text/css">
 html, body { margin:0; padding:0; }
 body, td, th, pre, code, select, option, input, textarea { font-family:verdana,arial,sans-serif; font-size:10px; }
 .demo, .demo input, .jstree-dnd-helper, #vakata-contextmenu { font-size:10px; font-family:Verdana; }
 #container { width:780px; margin:10px auto; overflow:hidden; position:relative; }
 #demo { width:auto; height:400px; overflow:auto; border:1px solid gray; }

 #text { margin-top:1px; }

 #alog { font-size:9px !important; margin:5px; border:1px solid silver; }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="demo1">
 <a href="some_value_here">Node title</a>
 <ul>
  <li>
   saaa
   <!-- UL node only needed for children - omit if there are no children -->
   <ul>
    <li>aaa</li>
    <li>sss</li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
 $("#demo1").jstree({ 
  "themes": {
         "theme": "default",
         "dots": true,
         "icons": true,
         "url": "themes/default/style.css"
       },
  "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data" ]
 });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

my result is omploader.org/vNWJibg :

you can see ,it does not has any themes ,

so how to get it work ,

thanks

**updated:**

this is my result  pic : omploader.org/vNWJjbQ/1.png

how to get it work .

**updated2**

oh , i got it , it must be `<a>` element in the `<li>`

this is my code :

```
<div id="demo1">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="">aaa</a>
            <!-- UL node only needed for children - omit if there are no children -->
            <ul>
                <li><a href=""> kkk</a></li>
                <li><a href=""> kkk</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Hope you dont think deleting your comment will make us forget it.

Comment: @Iznogood: I deleted that.  I'm not sure what prompted it, but there's no place for it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you don't have an ID on your div. Change `<div id="">` to `<div id="demo1">`.